# building two projects from shared files

Tags: typescript, webpack, tsconfig

I have a React frontend and a node backend residing in the same git repository with the following directory structure:

root
--client/
----src/
------types/
------lib/
------components/
----dist/
--server/
----src/
------types/
------routes/
------lib/
----dist/

Client and server both have their own `tsconfig.json` and `webpack.config.json` files.
I have some files that I would like to use in both client and server, such as the types (`client/types/index.d.ts` and `server/types/index.d.ts`) and some strings for localization (`client/lib/strings/index.ts` and `server/lib/strings/index.ts`).
How can I move these files that I require for both to the root and still have both frontend and backend compile them into the respective `dist/` directories?

Comment: Use the common as dependencies then import them into client and server as needed.